# How to automatically display a user email in an HTML form field using Google Apps Script and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've created an HTML form using Google HTML service. How do I automatically display the user's email in the email field when they open the form?  I already have a function for `onload` for the date. I tried using `google.script.run`, but it's not working. Here is my HTML code:

```
<body onload="todaysDate()"> 
  <form>
    <label><span> Requestor:  </span><input id="reqEmail" type="text" name="reqEmail" placeholder="Your email..."></label>      
        <br>       
        <label><span>Requestor's department:  </span><input id="reqDept" type="text" name="reqDepartment" placeholder="Your deparment..."></label>
        <br>        
        <label><span>Date of Submission:  </span><input id="subDate" type="text" name="dateSubmission"></label>
        <br> 
        <label><span>Required delivery date:  </span><input id="delDate" type="date" name="dateDelivery"></label>
        <br>
   </form>
</body>
```

Here is my Code.gs:

```
//Get user email
function getUserEmail() {
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();  
  Logger.log(userEmail);
}
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
//Insert todays's date to "Date of Submission"
var d = new Date();
var curr_day = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() +1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

function todaysDate() {
document.getElementById('subDate').value=(curr_month + "-" + curr_day + "-" + curr_year);

};

google.script.run.getUserEmail(userEmail);
var email = document.getElementById('reqEmail'); 
email.value = userEmail;
```

Comment: I changed the input type to "email" in the HTML form, but still not working.

Comment: see the official docs on how to receive data from a google.script.run call

Comment: @ Zig Mandel, I did read the official docs here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run, but they don't provide much information.  I've scouraged the internet and can't find an example and I've tried many different things.  I'm sure there's a way to do it but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) but still worth mentioning.

How does `google.script.run` work? It just runs a function on "server" side. This server side function can `return` some result (which was suggested by Darren in the previous answer) but you'd still need to tell your script what to do with this result afterwards.

And if you want to do something with the result on client side, you'll need to use `.withSuccessHanlder` part — with its help you specify your client side function which will accept the result of the server function's work. In your case — this result is the user email. So it'll be something like `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(todaysDate).getUserEmail()` — you aren't passing any parameters to `getUserEmail()` because it doesn't need them.

But you need to change your `todaysDate()` function a bit.

```
function todaysDate(userEmail) {
  document.getElementById('subDate').value = (curr_month + "-" + curr_day + "-" + curr_year);
  document.getElementById('reqEmail').value = userEmail; 
};
```

And instead of assigning an `onload` function to the `<body>` tag you can just add this line into your `<script>` `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(todaysDate).getUserEmail();`.

As a whole, it'll look something like this:

```
<script>

//Insert todays's date to "Date of Submission"
var d = new Date();
var curr_day = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() +1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(todaysDate).getUserEmail();
function todaysDate(userEmail) {
  document.getElementById('subDate').value = (curr_month + "-" + curr_day + "-" + curr_year);
  document.getElementById('reqEmail').value = userEmail; 
};

</script>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you for your help and great explanation!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really familiar with the Google HTML Service but if it works like regular javascript then you should be able to:

- Update the 'getUserEmail' function to return the email address:

```
//Get user email
function getUserEmail() {
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    Logger.log(userEmail);
    return userEmail;
}
```

- Update your javascript to receive the email address:

```
var userEmail = getUserEmail();
var email = document.getElementById('reqEmail');
email.value = userEmail;
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it's still not showing up in the field.